# Looking for a web part (default)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, spfx-webparts

So I have a web part on a site and I want to know where it is from. To me, it seems to be one of the default one, although I havent been able to find it. It works like a header/title with title, background and a persona with name/mail adress. See the attached images. First one is of the property pane. Its the default web part that acts as a header/title when you create a new page, but can you add it manually?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a web-part. This is SharePoint OOTB page title customization for modern page only. That you will see when every you creating new modern page.

You can edit it after page created. To Edit you have to edit page and click on top left corner to edit page title. You can refer below image

Note: This is only work for Modern Page
[image]

Comment: I know, but can you add it AFTER you create a new page?

Comment: yes, for modern page

Comment: How can it be added? Tried to search for it, but could not find an option to add this in an already existing page in edit mode.

Comment: I have updated answer you can find there